# Cohort in R keeping unique values

Tags: r, data.table

My data has a list of 5 million customers which have been acquired along with acquisition date. Also some 3 million customers have transacted till date

I want to figure out a way to plot the data to find out the customers who transacted out of the acquired base across months

Sample data

CID is customer id
yw is transacted month and year
month_year is acquired month and year

```
CID       yw        month_year  
1000000   2018-01    2010-02
1000001   2018-05    2017-05 
1000002   2018-06    2017-05
1000002   2019-06    2017-05    
1000003   2018-12    2015-04
1000004   2019-07    2019-01
1000005   2020-09    2020-06
1000006    NA        2017-05
```

There are some acquired customers who have not transacted also like 1000006.
There are some customers like 1000002 who transacted multiple times and I want to count this only once which will be minimum transaction month which is 2018-06 only

```
Output 
         Acquired   NA  2018-01 2018-05 2018-06 2018-12 2019-07 2020-09
2010-02     1             1
2015-04     1                                     1
2017-05     3        1             1       1       
2019-01     1                                            1
2020-06     1                                                     1
```

tried this code

```
data_a <- df_b[c(1,1:nrow(df_b)),]
setDT(data_a)
(cohorts <- dcast(unique(data_a)[,cohort:=min(yw),by=user_id],cohort~month_year))

m <- as.matrix(cohorts[,-1])
rownames(m) <- cohorts[[1]]
m[lower.tri(m)] <- NA
names(dimnames(m)) <- c("cohort", "yearmon")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no need to create two separate DBs and then join... It can be done straightaway like this.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(CID) %>% arrange(trans_date) %>%
  slice_head() %>% #filtered only first trans date per customer
  group_by(acq_date) %>%
  mutate(acquired = n()) %>% # created acquired column
  group_by(acq_date, trans_date) %>%
  mutate(dummy = n()) %>% ungroup() %>% #created values to be filled
  arrange(acq_date) %>% #optional
  select(-CID) %>%
  #for customers having same transdate and acq_date
  group_by(trans_date, acq_date, acquired, dummy) %>% slice_head() %>% ungroup() %>%
  #creating final output
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(acquired, acq_date), names_from = trans_date, values_from = dummy, values_fill =NULL)
 # A tibble: 5 x 9
  acquired acq_date `2018-01` `2018-05` `2018-06` `2018-12` `2019-07` `2020-09`  `NA`
     <int> <chr>        <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int> <int>
1        1 2010-02          1        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA    NA
2        3 2017-05         NA         1         1        NA        NA        NA     1
3        1 2015-04         NA        NA        NA         1        NA        NA    NA
4        1 2019-01         NA        NA        NA        NA         1        NA    NA
5        2 2020-06         NA        NA        NA        NA        NA         2    NA
```

To handle the cases where there may be more than one customer acquired in same month and doing first transaction during same month too, I have added one row to your sample data.

```
#dput used
> dput(df)
structure(list(CID = c(1000000L, 1000001L, 1000002L, 1000002L, 
1000003L, 1000004L, 1000005L, 1000006L, 1000007L), trans_date = c("2018-01", 
"2018-05", "2018-06", "2019-06", "2018-12", "2019-07", "2020-09", 
NA, "2020-09"), acq_date = c("2010-02", "2017-05", "2017-05", 
"2017-05", "2015-04", "2019-01", "2020-06", "2017-05", "2020-06"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
> 

> df
      CID trans_date acq_date
1 1000000    2018-01  2010-02
2 1000001    2018-05  2017-05
3 1000002    2018-06  2017-05
4 1000002    2019-06  2017-05
5 1000003    2018-12  2015-04
6 1000004    2019-07  2019-01
7 1000005    2020-09  2020-06
8 1000006       <NA>  2017-05
9 1000007    2020-09  2020-06
```

Comment: Please feel free to upvote the answer, as it helps the answerer and other users.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this is pretty crude, but I believe it works.

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
  CID       yw        month_year  
  1000000   2018-01    2010-02
  1000001   2018-05    2017-05 
  1000002   2018-06    2017-05
  1000002   2019-06    2017-05    
  1000003   2018-12    2015-04
  1000004   2019-07    2019-01
  1000005   2020-09    2020-06
  1000006   NA         2017-05
  ",
  header = TRUE)
```

**Filtering for unique customers with their earliest `yw` date**

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(CID) %>%
  arrange(yw) %>%
  slice_head() %>%
  ungroup()
```

**Obtaining the `Acquired` column**

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(month_year) %>%
  mutate(Acquired = n()) %>%
  select(month_year, Acquired) %>%
  distinct(month_year, Acquired)
```

**Putting it all together**

```
df %>%
  group_by(yw, month_year) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  # long to wide
  pivot_wider(month_year, names_from = yw, values_from = n) %>%
  left_join(df2) %>%
  # rearranging columns
  select(month_year, Acquired, `NA`, everything())
```

Comment: Joining, by = "Month_Yr"
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `NA` doesn't exist.